# Initialize Lists in NSwag generated client

Tags: nswag

I use NSwag in VS 2019 with connected service to generate my API Client in a Blazor WASM Application. On my asp.net webapi I have a model with collections like:

```
    public List<SupportTermDto> SupportTerms { get; set; } = new List<SupportTermDto>();
```

The generated code for those is:

```
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("supportTerms", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SupportTermDto> SupportTerms { get; set; }
```

So they are initialized to `null`. Is it possible to tell the generator to initialize lists with an empty collection?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It can be done if you add a [Required] attribute on the List but its not a perfect way to go. Also, it would be great if the List was also a List and not an ICollection in the generated code.

Comment: Not really. What might be an idea is if you share your DTO's with your wasm client and then don't let them generate by nswag. That way you could create the DTO's yourself. But that is just an idea, haven't tried it myself :)

Comment: @Vindberg Actually, I played around a bit with NSwagStudio. that has the option to change the default list type aswell as initialize them with a default and without setter. So you get something like this: `public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TimeTrackingDto> TimeTrackingList { get; } = default!;`.
I think that should be the answer here.

Comment: Im using VS 2022 Nswag (Not Studio) - can't find a way to change that particular options?

Comment: nswag studio is a separate tool: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio